# Split a selected word(s) in characters and add spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for a way to split and uppercase the currently *selected* text in an input field.  I only want the selected text, not the entire value of the field.  After clicking a button, I want to have that selected text be split into individual characters, separated by spaces, and upper-cased.

Here is an example:

before: word

after: W O R D

Here is a graphical illustration of what I'm trying to achieve: [image: Because am image worth a thousand words]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button><br>

<input type="text" value="Write here">
```

Comment: `"#demo".split('').join(' ');` - what?..

Comment: sorry wrong copy and paste. The #demo was an old one. Anyway... As you see comment could be helpful ! ;)

Comment: `":input".split('').join(' ')` - whaaaaat?..

Comment: You're just splitting and joining the string ":input", do you realize that?

Comment: define `selected word` and selected from what source? Show proper sample input and expected results. Question is lacking in proper [mcve] and has an inadequate problem statement

Comment: The problem is in very idea. When you click the button your input lost focus and thus selection.

Comment: "selected word" to me is a text written in the input and Selected / undeline with the mouse. After the "selection" you click the button... then you have the new "design". Sorry, try to be as clean as I can !

Comment: @charlietfl : I made an update on my question. Because am image worth a thousand words ;)

Comment: All you need is a simple `String.replace()` Still could use a proper explanation beyond the picture but if you just want to update input `replace()` would work fine

Comment: Excellent portrayal of forum monitoring by downvoting without saying why.  This is why there are so many negative comments about stackexchange outside of this site.  SHM.

Comment: @Dale : I totally agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my interpretation of what you've described:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input = $("textarea");
    var istart = input[0].selectionStart;
    var iend = input[0].selectionEnd;
    var val = input.val();
    var seltext = val.substr(istart, iend-istart).split("").join(" ");
    var newval = val.substring(0, istart) + seltext.toUpperCase() + val.substring(iend, val.length);
    input.val(newval);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button><br>

<textarea>Write here</textarea>
```

I have removed the handler for the `select` event on the input, and left the `click` event on the button as the initiator to split the selection.

Comment: So nice to be understood ! thank you Michael ! This is exactly it.

Comment: Sorry. Just found out that I wanted to use "textarea" intead of "input" any idea of how it could work out ?

Comment: @Simtwo I just updated the example to support a `<textarea>` element.  Check out the code snippet, and you'll see that it works great.

Comment: Thank you for everything you've done ! works perfecty

Comment: @Simtwo glad to help.  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

I made a little jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/20rmguhu/
The Code should be pretty much self explaining. Just ask if it isn't.
You don't really need jQuery for this, but if you want you can replace the `querySelector` and `addEventListener` with jQuery functions.

html:

```
<input id="myInput" value="Write here">
<button>Click me</button>
```

Js:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var myInput = document.querySelector("#myInput");

    var text = myInput.value;
    var selectionStart = myInput.selectionStart;
    var selectionEnd = myInput.selectionEnd;

    var selectedText = text.substr(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    var textBefore = text.substr(0, selectionStart);
    var textAfter = text.substr(selectionEnd);

    // make the text uppercase and add spaces between each letter
    selectedText = selectedText.toUpperCase().split("").join(" ");
    myInput.value = textBefore + selectedText + textAfter;

    // select the changed text again
    myInput.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionStart + selectedText.length);
});
```